# Set os.getcwd() as default in path in python call

Tags: python-3.x, linux, path

I have a project with some sources like this:

- `./src/core/settings.py`
- `./src/inteface/api.py`
- `./src/inteface/worker.py`

Both interfaces (`api.py` and `worker.py`) do a import like `from core.settings import some_setting`

I'm running:

```bash
cd ./src
pyhton ./inteface/worker.py
```

And Getting  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'`

There is any way to run this apps with `./src` as cwd without explicit add `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` in my code?

Comment: Try `export PYTHONPATH+=:.` after `cd ./src`